# Writing Ruby inject method?

Tags: ruby

Im a bit confused at why this answer is "wrong" based on Ruby's own interpretation of the "Inject" method (for an array in this case, Im doing the "Odin Projects" projects for learning tasks)

```
def my_inject(start = nil)
  memo = self[0] if start.nil?
  for i in 0...self.length do
    puts "#{memo}:#{self[i]} Results=#{yield(memo,self[i])}"
    memo = yield(memo,self[i])
  end
  return memo
end



[5,6,7,8,9,10].my_inject { |sum, n| sum + n }
```

The Above returns this specifically:

```
5:5 Results=10
10:6 Results=16
16:7 Results=23
23:8 Results=31
31:9 Results=40
40:10 Results=50
=> 50
```

Which makes sense right? When no starting value is defined, the first value is used. However according to Ruby's API docs:["Inject"](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) it should be 45....

Which doesn't make sense to me. We start with a memo of the first value and add it to the "elements" value. Which is 10 (in this case)...and so forth. Or are they saying when you DO NOT specify a value? you should skip the first array value?

I mean if I add up 5+6+7+8+9+10 yeah that is correctly 45, but if im doing what the block wants me to do, I feel like "50" makes more sense? Although obviously im wrong, im just not sure where.

I mean sure I could start the index off at 1 if we are not given a starting value...but that just seems odd.

Thanks

Comment: I think you've answered your own question... 5+6+7+8+9+10 = 45 - so I think it clearly makes most sense for that method to return 45, not 50. Why do you think 50 makes more sense??

Comment: And yes, the implementation is that "if you don't supply an initial value, then the iterator skips this". This implementation provides "unsurprising" behaviour, unlike your method that double-counts the first array element.

Comment: Your entire reasoning sounds as though it's based on "how you feel the method ought to be defined", rather than the more logical question: "What should the method return?"

Comment: Note that Ruby code hardly ever uses `for` as the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html) method `each` and associated helpers is far more flexible. Additionally, `return` at the end of a Ruby method is redundant, those values are returned implicitly, so in this case simply `memo` is sufficient.

Comment: I guess it's confusing to me, because yes I realize it's wrong and I realize that it double taps the first element..but I just think that it's trying to run the block...so "memo" in this case would be 5 as would the value it's on. So 5+5..which makes sense in terms of the block, but not when thinking about the problem as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As people have pointed out in comments, your solution double taps the first element if no argument is provided.

Here's an implementation that is pretty straightforward, drops some unnecessary elements your solution included, and works for more than just arrays:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_inject(memo = nil)
    each { |x| memo = memo.nil? ? x : yield(memo, x) }
    memo
  end
end

p (1..5).my_inject(&:*)                               # 5 factorial  =>  120
p (1..5).my_inject(2, &:*)                            # 5 factorial doubled => 240
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject(&:+)                            # string concatenation => "345"
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject("hello", &:+)                   # concatenation w/ prefix => "hello345"
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject("howdy") { |memo, x| memo + x } # prefix and block => "howdy345"
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

If you want to go further and handle `Symbol` or `String` arguments as `Enumerable#inject` does, you need to do some preprocessing to determine what you're dealing with:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_inject(memo = nil, sym = nil, &block)
    memo = memo.to_sym if memo.is_a?(String) && !sym && !block
    block, memo = memo.to_proc, nil if memo.is_a?(Symbol) && !sym
    sym = sym.to_sym if sym.is_a?(String)
    block = sym.to_proc if sym.is_a?(Symbol)

    # Ready to rock & roll
    each { |x| memo = memo.nil? ? x : block.yield(memo, x) }
    memo
  end
end

# A variety of test cases    
p (1..4).my_inject(:*)                                # 4 factorial via Symbol =>  24
p (1..5).my_inject('*')                               # 5 factorial via String =>  120
p (1..6).my_inject { |memo, x| memo * x }             # 6 factorial via block => 720
p (1..5).my_inject(2, &:*)                            # 5 factorial doubled via Proc => 240
p (1..5).my_inject(3, :*)                             # 5 factorial tripled via Symbol =>  360
p (1..5).my_inject(4, '*')                            # 5 factorial quadrupled via String =>  480
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject(&:+)                            # string concatenation via Proc => "345"
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject("hello", &:+)                   # prefix and Proc => "hello345"
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject("howdy") { |memo, x| memo + x } # prefix and block => "howdy345"
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject("yowza", :+)                    # prefix and Symbol => "yowza345"
p %w(3 4 5).my_inject("yoiks", '+')                   # prefix and String => "yoiks345"
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to double tap the argument when you look at the block `sum + n` which is what is being passed. In that case "sum" is 5 (using the first value) and n is on the first value (So 5+5)....which obviously is wrong. I think im taking the explanation too literally because when I see on the Ruby docs that "it uses the first array element as the sum" I think I literally should be passing in the first array element into the block and running it normally (Which is wrong I understand)

Comment: I think Tom Lord explained it pretty well, `inject` with a sum is supposed to sum the values, so 45 is the correct answer for your example.